# Windows Phone 8 Lock screen timeout option in settings

Tags: windows-phone-8, lockscreen

A couple of questions regarding the Windows Phone 8 lock screen:

1. The windows phone 8 emulator has an option "Never" in the lock screen time out settings. Why is this option not available in actual Windows Phone 8 devices (I have checked the Nokia Lumia 820 and HTC 8S)?
2. Can the Lock screen time-out be set programmatically?

Comment: It has been speculated that the option is enabled/disabled by different carriers depending on the type of screen for the device (disabled to prevent any burn-in/damage to the screen). See the discussion at: http://forums.wpcentral.com/nokia-lumia-1020/235999-ok-what-happened-never-option-lock-screen-timeout-irritating-hell.html

Answer (score 3):

It's available. It's HTC 8S (International EU)

Yes, you can do this by disabling UserIdleDetection.

Samples and more background info here.

[PhoneApplicationService.UserIdleDetectionMode Property (Microsoft.Phone.Shell)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[Idle Detection for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[image]